# Unable to concatenate strings

Tags: python, string, encryption, concatenation, encode

I am trying to make an encoding program for a cipher I made and I was unable to concatenate strings, here is my code:

```
charToBin = {
  "a":1,
  "b":10,
  "c":11,
  "d":100,
  "e":101,
  "f":110,
  "g":111,
  "h":1000
}
binToWrd = {
  1:"Intel",
  10:"Info",
  11:"Indipendent",
  101:"Imposibble",
  100:"Info-stolen",
  110:"Indian-Ogres",
  111:"Initially",
  1000:"Infant-Orphan-Ogre-Ogle"
}

endTxt = " "
cipher = " "

def txtToBin():

  txt = input(":")
  txtArray = txt.split(" ")
  for x in range(len(txt)):
    endTxt += str(charToBin[txtArray[x]])+" "
  print(endTxt)

def binToCip():
  codeTxtArr = endTxt.split(" ")
  for x1 in codeTxtArr:
    for x2 in binToWrd:
      cipher =+ x1.replace(str(x2), binToWrd[x2])
  print(cipher)

txtToBin()
binToCip()
```

It returned this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 40, in <module>
    txtToBin()
  File "main.py", line 30, in txtToBin
    endTxt = endTxt + str(charToBin[txtArray[x]])+" "
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'endTxt' referenced before assignment
```

Can anyone explain why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the initialization of `endTxt` inside `txtToBin()`:

```py
def txtToBin():
  endTxt = " "
  txt = input(":")
  txtArray = txt.split(" ")
  for x in range(len(txt)):
    endTxt += str(charToBin[txtArray[x]])+" "
  print(endTxt)
```

**Edit:** OP added additional constraints after the answer was initially posted. We can pass variables in as parameters to resolve the issue of sharing variables across multiple functions.

```py
def txtToBin():
  endTxt = " "
  txt = input(":")
  txtArray = txt.split(" ")
  for x in range(len(txt)):
    endTxt += str(charToBin[txtArray[x]])+" "
  return endTxt

def binToCip(endTxt):
  cipher = " "
  codeTxtArr = endTxt.split(" ")
  for x1 in codeTxtArr:
    for x2 in binToWrd:
      cipher += x1.replace(str(x2), binToWrd[x2])
  return cipher
  
endTxt = txtToBin()
print(endTxt)
print(binToCip(endTxt))
```

Comment: I forgot to add a part that is important It is there now could you answer again?

Comment: Where are they?

Comment: `=+` should be `+=`. Regardless, edited.

Comment: It adds another error of same type

Comment: What error, specifically? I'm not able to produce any errors on my end.

Comment: Oh, I will try again

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could still initialize `endTxt` outside just declare it as a global in your function (whether that's good practice is a separate question)

```py
charToBin = {
  "a":1,
  "b":10,
  "c":11,
  "d":100,
  "e":101,
  "f":110,
  "g":111,
  "h":1000
}
binToWrd = {
  1:"Intel",
  10:"Info",
  11:"Indipendent",
  101:"Imposibble",
  100:"Info-stolen",
  110:"Indian-Ogres",
  111:"Initially",
  1000:"Infant-Orphan-Ogre-Ogle"
}

endTxt = " "
cipher = " "

def txtToBin():
  global endTxt # add this
  txt = input(":")
  txtArray = txt.split(" ")
  for x in range(len(txt)):
    endTxt += str(charToBin[txtArray[x]])+" "
  print(endTxt)

def binToCip():
  global cipher # and this
  codeTxtArr = endTxt.split(" ")
  for x1 in codeTxtArr:
    for x2 in binToWrd:
      cipher += x1.replace(str(x2), binToWrd[x2])
  print(cipher)

txtToBin()
binToCip()
```

Also just a suggestion in your `charToBin` dictionary you don't have to write it down for every letter just use the following code:

```py
def char_to_bin(char):
    if char.isalpha():
        num = ord(char.lower()) - 96
        return f"{num:8b}".strip()
    else:
        raise KeyError
```

Explanation: 
If you're not familiar with ASCII, first check it out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). The ord function returns the ascii code (in base 10) for any character and we know lowercase letters begin from 97 so we can just subtract 97 from the returned value but you're counting from 1, so we'll subtract 96. the return statement has an f-string you can check the micro-syntax for the f-string [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). Basically the f-string is just converting the binary representation of the the character to a string but the conversion adds spaces to the unused places (since the string has to be 8 in size as declared by us in the f-string), so to remove the extra spaces `.strip()` was used.

Comment: Could you explain how the second code block you showed works, please? And I forgot to add a part that is important It is there now could you answer again?

Comment: How do I make something global in a function

Comment: you use the following syntax `global name_of_variable`

Comment: i did that 
global endTxt += str(charToBin[txtArray[x]])+" "
and it said invalid syntax

Comment: No you can't assign while declaring a global variable, just look at the code in the answer to see how to achieve this, but do note @BrokenBenchmark's way of doing this is better

Comment: Got it!Thanks a lot!